# Prevent unwanted commands from Emacs being loaded into completion and help buffers

Tags: emacs

I am begining to develop my own Emacs environment, I have a custom init.el (as below) that loads libraries from my user directory and ignores the installed directories. I have not placed any of the Amusement or Mail lisp libraries in the User directory but they are still appearing in auto-complete lists. This is because they are being defined as auto-load functions. How do I prevent these auto-load functions from being created?  I don't want to individually remove each unwanted function as this is cumbersome and wasteful.

Help info on an unwanted function;

```
5x5 is an interactive autoloaded Lisp function.

It is bound to <menu-bar> <tools> <games> <5x5>.
```

my init.el;

```
(setq inhibit-defaul-init 1)

(setq load-path (list 
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/")
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp/emacs-lisp/")
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp/eshell/")
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp/net/")
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp/nxml")
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp/org")        
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp/term")
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp/textmodes")
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp/usrl")
     (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp/")
    )
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unbind autoloaded functions in the same way that you can unbind normal functions, so you could effectively remove `5x5` and other unwanted autoloaded functions from the running system like this:

```el
(mapc
 (lambda (func) (fmakunbound func))
 '(5x5 5x5-crack-randomly 5x5-crack-mutating-current 5x5-crack-mutating-best 5x5-crack-xor-mutate 5x5-crack))
```

For autoloaded variables, you would use `makunbound` instead of `fmakunbound`.

To obtain a list of likely suspects, you could use

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `loaddefs` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `occur` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^(autoload` <kbd>RET</kbd>

The `loadhist` library might also be of interest.

**Edit:**

Actually, inspecting the autoload file seems like a *fairly* safe method of establishing whether or not you want to eliminate something. I believe this is only usable with functions, however; as far as I can see, other kinds of autoloaded objects are just defined immediately by loaddefs. You could make assumptions based on symbol-name, but I wouldn't recommend it (but then I wouldn't do any of this, so YMMV).

```el
(defvar my-unwanted-libraries
  '("5x5" "snake" "hanoi" "tetris")
  "Unbind all autoloaded functions for these libraries.")

(defun my-unbind-unwanted-autoload-functions ()
  "Unbind all unwanted autoloaded functions."
  (interactive)
  (do-symbols (symbol)
    (let* ((function (and (fboundp symbol)
                          (symbol-function symbol)))
           (file (and function
                      (consp function)
                      (eq (car function) 'autoload)
                      (cadr function))))
      (when (and file (member file my-unwanted-libraries))
        (fmakunbound symbol)))))
```

Comment: The provided function my-unbind-unwanted-autoload-functions undbinds the unwanted functions readable and manageable format, start up time is likely to be slower than Trey Jacksons response but portability is more important in this case.

Comment: The above worked fine until I removed common lisp functions from my environment, I've added the auto-load declaration for do-symbols for those that aren't already using it.

Answer (score 2):

Since most of Emacs is written in Emacs Lisp, and as much as possible is auto-loaded, you cannot easily remove the functions set up for auto loading.  For example, `c++-mode` is an autoloaded function, so getting rid of all autoloaded functions would prevent you from using `c++-mode` (unless you'd added your own copy).

Probably the best way to do what you are asking is to build your own Emacs executable, and restrict what gets put into the Emacs executable itself.  This is documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Building-Emacs.html).  You could simply remove the directories/libraries you don't want, and rebuild.  The newly generated autoload file wouldn't contain references to the functions in those libraries, and you'd be all set.

*Note:* you may inadvertently remove libraries that are used by Emacs that you don't realize.  For example, <kbd>M-x report-emacs-bug</kbd> uses Email...

Is there a particular reason you want to remove these autoloaded functions?  If you feel they're cluttering up completions, there are many many completion libraries you can use to customize what you see.

Comment: Building an executable with different lisp files preloaded covers exactly what I asked for. However I am avoiding this solution because of the reduced portability. Should someone only work on a few private machines this is the better method.